# Command-D from startup options doesn't start Apple Diagnostics on 2021 M1 MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)

Tags: apple-silicon, apple-diagnostics

Use Apple Diagnostics to test your Mac: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Steps:

**Apple silicon**

1. Turn on your Mac and continue to press and hold the power button as your Mac starts up.
2. Release when you see the startup options window, which includes a gear icon labeled Options.
3. Press Command (⌘)-D on your keyboard.

**Expected**:

Apple diagnostics starts

**Actual**:

1. Message "Continue holding to start diagnostics" appears
2. With Cmd-D held down, Mac reboots a few seconds later
3. Apple logo appears for 1-2s
4. Apple logo disappears briefly and reappears for 1-2s
5. Loading bar appears under Apple logo
6. User dropped to "Startup Disk" with prompt to unlock FDE
7. Unlocking disk allows user to select disk with MacOS to reboot
8. Booting with this disk selected, no diagnostics are run

**Other troubleshooting**:

- There is no firmware password as this is a M1 device.
- Secure boot options (full security vs any signed OS) doesn't seem to impact this either